# Realtime communication java to javascript

Tags: java, javascript, communication

I have a java program which collects realtime sensor data from a COM port and I want to send it to javascript without using node.js.

The sensor data should be givin arround at least 2 times a second.

I tough about using a database to communicate but that's probably to slow a solution.
Browser support can be limited to google chrome if needed. (osx,win,linux)

What would be your ideal solution?

**EDIT : -**  the java software should run on the same platform as the webbased javascript client.

Essentially the data being send is GPS,.. data which is shown on a map.

Comment: Can you use a Socket? A Socket can handle about 200,000 messages per second.

Comment: Just write a web application. profit.

Comment: Where will the java program run, and where will the JavaScript program run?

Comment: both will run on the same platform; currently the java and javascript are 2 different applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can do this.

-A java  to flash to JavaScript bridge to communicate via sockets. This is the most compatible way since most browsers support flash. There are a few opensource AS3 bridges however you need sockets.

-A java applet and from the applet invoke JavaScript Code.If you have permission to read the com port is the easiest way otherwise you may have to struggle with applet certifications. The Java Runtime  must be installed on your machine.

-A websocket if you use Firefox 8.0+ or a recent versión of google chrome to communicate with your java app wia websockets. Is the most modern way to do it. It will not work with IE but you don't need any other app as bridge between javascript and java, you may need to struggle to find a java socket server example, create your own implementation or use a web containger/app server that supports WS:// or WSS://

Comment: what is better resource wise? because a lot of sensor data is transmitted: use of an applet or socket comm?

Comment: that would depends on your needs. If its some kind of monitor I would create a flash/flex real time monitor and connect it via sockets to your java app that reads from the com. If you want to do it with cutting edge code tech I would use a websocket and connect it to your com reader java app.
The easiest would be to create a java applet and if you can read the com from there invoke the javascript when need.(you don't need sockets with this one).
don't worry about socket efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

[LiveConnect](http://jdk6.java.net/plugin2/liveconnect/) is what you're looking for. It allows you to define communication methods  from JS to Java and viceversa. And it's a built-in technology in the JDK.

Comment: does this mean I need to convert my java program to an applet?

Comment: basically you'd use an applet class that handles the calls to and from JS, and propagate what you get to the rest of the program. I realized a audio recorder in this way, using JS for enabling and disabling it (I didn't want to use java applet GUI) and for all the other basic operations. All the recording functionalities were in classic Java classes, while the applet contained everything for the frontend management and interaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

//JAVA


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        if (!(engine instanceof Invocable)) {
            System.out.println("Invoking methods is not supported.");
            return;
        }
        Invocable inv = (Invocable) engine;
        String scriptPath = "/Users/sheikhhussain/IdeaProjects/JavaHome/src/calculator.js";

        engine.eval("load('" + scriptPath + "')");

        Object calculator = engine.get("calculator");

        int x = 3;
        int y = 4;

        Object addResult = inv.invokeMethod(calculator, "add", x, y);
        Object subResult = inv.invokeMethod(calculator, "subtract", x, y);
        Object mulResult = inv.invokeMethod(calculator, "multiply", x, y);
        Object divResult = inv.invokeMethod(calculator, "divide", x, y);

        System.out.println(addResult.toString());
        System.out.println(subResult);
        System.out.println(mulResult);
        System.out.println(divResult);
    }
}



        // JAVASCRIPT

        var calculator = new Object();
        calculator.add = function (n1, n2) "jjj";
        calculator.subtract = function (n1, n2) n1 - n2;
        calculator.multiply = function (n1, n2) n1 * n2;
        calculator.divide = function (n1, n2) n1 / n2;
```